# find and get object array that matches value (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Below is a sample of some of my obj arrays I'm getting within my json response:

```
0: {day: "7", starting_time: "0800", closing_time: "1600"}
1: {day: "1", starting_time: "0600", closing_time: "1600"}
2: {day: "2", starting_time: "0600", closing_time: "1600"}
3:
closing_time: "1600"
day: "3"
starting_time: "0600"
__proto__: Object
```

I get the current day of the weeks value with the below:

```
  var d = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
  var hour = d.getHours();
```

I am simply trying to use the `dayOfWeek` value that I'm getting above (i.e. today it's `5`) - and use that to get array obj `5:` from my json to get that (*this*) days working hours from json response.

*Below is what I have tried recently.*

```
  function matchingDay(hoursoperations) {
    return hoursoperations === dayOfWeek;
  }
  console.log(myJson.bla.findIndex(matchingDay));
```

but I am getting error:

```
index.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myJson.bla.findIndex not a function
```

---

more context, data comes from fetch API.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  loadSVGs();
  fetch('https://www.website.com/obfuscate-json/obfuscate/v3/options/obfuscate')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
  // ....  code ...
```

Comment: where is method xxxx where is promise? Could you replicate this in a fiddle maybe?

Comment: I have added that info and un-obfuscated it

Comment: ok it seems that myJson is not an array its an object

Comment: it is an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

Your function is fine just that myJson.bla is not an array but an object with keys '0', '1' ... if you don't care about those indices

```
function matchingDay(hoursoperations) {
  return hoursoperations === dayOfWeek;
}
console.log(Object.values(myJson.bla).findIndex(matchingDay));
```

You can further modify your method to compare with the attribute day

```
function matchingDay(row) {
  return +row.day === dayOfWeek;
}
console.log(Object.values(myJson.bla).findIndex(matchingDay));
```

Comment: thanks, so no errors with this however it prints a -1 in the console - as opposed to getting 5

Comment: modify your method to calculate based on an attribute of the object day, start/close time

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your question isn't exactly clear, but It would make sense to use the `Array.prototype.find()` method.
for example:

```
  var d = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
  var hour = d.getHours();

// now finding the object with the exact day of the week.
  jsonResponse.find(obj => dayOfWeek+1 == obj.day);
```

the `.find()` method returns an element in the array once the condition passed evaluates to true.

also, days of the week in javascript start from `0-6`, so to get the matching day of the week, you have to increment the day of the week by 1.